# How to replace Email id text before @ with * in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, string, email, swift3, replacewith

Hello I have not get perfect solution for how to replace Email Id text before @ with * like

suppose my email id is **`XXXXXXX@gmail.com`** then my output I want like `*******@gmail.com`

I try like this

```
    let delimiter = "@"
    let newstr = "Himmoradiya@gmail.com"
    var token = newstr.components(separatedBy: delimiter)

    let newQuery = (token[0] as NSString).replacingCharacters(
        in: NSMakeRange(0,token[0].characters.count), with: "*")
```

Any suggestion is accepted.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nx6ghgl3kpfsns/ServiceCall.swift?dl=0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `init(repeating:count:)`

```
  let newstr = "Himmoradiya@gmail.com"
  var token = newstr.components(separatedBy: "@")
  let newQuery = String(repeating: "*", count: token[0].characters.count)  //check array length before using index
  print(newQuery + "@" +  token[1] ) // *******@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this code:

```
let aString = "This is my string"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "*")
```

Comment: He wants to replace character before @ but your code will replace @ with *

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
    let delimiter = "@"
    let newstr = "Himmoradiya@gmail.com"
    let arr = newstr.components(separatedBy: delimiter)

    let resultStr = "xxxxxx" + "@" + arr[1]

    print(resultStr)
```

Comment: Static values also fine...Missing '@' in result.

Comment: @DSDharma : yeah right, have missed `@` ! edited it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function .

```
func getStarred(_ email : String ) -> String
    {
        var didFoundATRO = false
        var tempString = ""
        for char in email.characters
        {
            if char == "@"
            {
                didFoundATRO = true
            }

            if !didFoundATRO
            {
                tempString += "*"
            }
            else
            {
                tempString.append(char)
            }
        }
        return tempString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        let delimiter = "@"
        var newstr = "Himmoradiya@gmail.com"
        let arr = newstr.components(separatedBy: delimiter)
        let strMail = arr.first!
        let strReplaceStr = String(repeating: "*", count: strMail.characters.count)
        newstr =  newstr.replacingOccurrences(of: strMail, with: strReplaceStr)
```

and output (`newstr`) will be : ***********@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I have created a string extension like...

```
extension String {

   var hideEmailPrefix: String {
      if self.contains("@") {
          var part = self.components(separatedBy: "@")
          let newText = String(repeating: "*", count: part[0].count)
          return newText + "@" + part[1]
      }
      return self
   }
}
```

Then in my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let email = "abc@gmail.com"
    print(email.hideEmailPrefix) // ***@gmail.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maskEmail: String {
        let email = self
        let components = email.components(separatedBy: "@")
        var maskEmail = ""
        if let first = components.first {
            maskEmail = String(first.enumerated().map { index, char in
                return [0, 1, first.count - 1, first.count - 2].contains(index) ? 
char : "*"
            })
        }
        if let last = components.last {
            maskEmail = maskEmail + "@" + last
        }
        return maskEmail
    }



 var maskPhoneNumber: String {
    return String(self.enumerated().map { index, char in
        return [0, 3, self.count - 1, self.count - 2].contains(index) ? 
    char : "*"
    })
     }
```